# "how to manipulate the microphone(laptop embedded microphone) using NAudio API?"

Tags: microphone, naudio

I would like to ask: "how to manipulate the microphone(laptop embedded microphone) using NAudio API?"

i don't like to record the sound that comes from the mic but measure it in terms of dB.

its like a faucet of water open and placing it through a water filter extracting every dirt(data) that comes along with the water.

Thank You.

Notes: Programming Language = C#.
Programming Knowledge = UnderGrad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NAudio, you will get the recorded data back as a byte array in the `DataAvailable` event. Assuming that you are recording at 16 bit, then you would take every two bytes and convert that to a short (Int16) using either the `BitConverter` class or doing your own bit manipulation.

This gives you sample values that you can process as you wish. To get a dB value you would then divide the absolute value of the sample by 32768, take its log (base 10) and then multiply by 20.